# Finding a name based on another column count

Tags: sql-server

I have this table `employee3_3`:

| id | name | department | managerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | A | null |
| 102 | Dan | A | 101 |
| 103 | James | A | 101 |
| 104 | Amy | A | 101 |
| 105 | Anne | A | 101 |
| 106 | Ron | A | 101 |

Here John is the manager, that's why he doesn't have a `managerId` value. But to prove he is the manager, I'm asked to write a query to find managers with at least five direct employees.

I tried this:

```
WITH cte AS
( 
    SELECT 
        name, managerid,
        (SELECT COUNT(b.managerid) 
         FROM employee3_3 AS b) AS result
    FROM
        employee3_3
)
SELECT employee3_3.name
FROM employee3_3
FULL JOIN cte ON employee3_3.name = cte.name
WHERE result = 5    
  AND cte.managerid = NULL
```

For some reason, it doesn't return any result.

I also tried this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  
        managerid, COUNT(managerid) AS number_of_employees
    FROM 
        employee3_3
    GROUP BY
        managerid, managerid
)
SELECT name
FROM employee3_3 AS e
JOIN cte ON e.managerid = cte.managerid
WHERE cte.number_of_employees <= 5
```

I'm not sure if is my approach that is wrong and I'm not in the right path, or if I'm not using the right functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.* 
from employee3_3 e
inner join
(select managerId
from employee3_3
group by managerId having count(*) >= 5 
) m on e.Id = m.managerId;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_y5wYC09)

PS: If a manager is meant to be her\his managerId is null then you should add that criteria (then only top level managers would count as manager)

Comment: thank you! and yeah Ill look into the criteria as you said

Answer (score 1):

Providing the DML as well as the example data is very helpful when asking questions like this.

It might be worth bearing in mind that this will only return rows for employees which have 5 or more direct reports. If a manager only has four direct reports, they would not be returned, regardless of how many people might report to those direct-reports:

Mary, Joe and Bill report to Bob.
Mary has 5 direct reports, Joe has 3 and Bill has 2.
Only Mary would be returned, even though Bob has a collective 13 reports. If you want/need to also have Bob returned we will need a recursive appraoch.

No need for a subquery here, just a self join:

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (id INT, name NVARCHAR(50), department VARCHAR(1), managerId INT)
INSERT INTO @Employees (id, name, department, managerId) VALUES
(101, 'John', 'A', null), (102, 'Dan', 'A', 101 ), (103, 'James', 'A', 101  ),
(104, 'Amy', 'A', 101   ), (105, 'Anne', 'A', 101   ), (106, 'Ron', 'A', 101);

SELECT e.id, e.name, e.department, e.managerId
  FROM @Employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Employees m
      ON e.id = m.managerId
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name, e.department, e.managerId
 HAVING COUNT(m.id) >= 5;
```

Comment: Oh yeah thats is good because a manager has to have at least 5 direct reports. Thank you for the extra information!